# How to prove that a $3\times 3$ matrix has only $2$ eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am working through a problem in Riley, Hobson and Bence (Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering) that revolves around the following matrix:

$$ A=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 0 \\
    -6 & 4 & 4 \\
    3 & -1 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

I first have to show that the eigenvalues are degenerate (all three eigenvalues are 2) and that any eigenvector takes the form:

$$ \vec{x}=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    u\\
    3u-2v\\
    v\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Proving these two statements are easy. The interesting part of the question asks to prove the following statement:

> If two pairs of values, $u_1, v_1$ and $u_2, v_2$, define two independent eigenvectors $\vec{x_1}$ and $\vec{x_2}$ , then any third similarly defined eigenvector $\vec{x_3}$ can be written as a linear combination of $\vec{x_1}$ and $\vec{x_2}$, i.e.
>
> $$\vec{x_3}=a\vec{x_1}+b\vec{x_2}$$
>
> Where:
>
> $$a=\frac{u_3v_2-u_2v_3}{u_1v_2-u_2v_1} \ \ \ \ \ \ b=\frac{u_1v_3-u_3v_1}{u_1v_2-u_2v_1}$$

I've been struggling with this for a while but I don't know where to start. Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: The column space of $A -2I$ is the eigenspace for your matrix. The only way to get three linearly independent eigenvectors is if $A - 2I = \mathbf{0}$. It is easily enough proven that this is not the case.

Comment: Please change the name of question ; it sounds very inappropriate.

Comment: Thank you @Hyperion for your answer. I looked into eigenspaces and that solved my problem. If you write up an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks, I will do so. I realize I made a mistake and said "column space" rather than the null space.

Comment: Your title doesn’t reflect the actual question that you ask here. That aside, the matrix does **not** have only two eigenvectors. Any nonzero scalar multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector, so it has an infinite number of them. On the other hand, the eigenspace associated with the eigenvalue $2$ is two-dimensional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The null space of the matrix $A - 2I$ is the eigenspace for your matrix. The only matrix for which three linearly independent solutions exist for the matrix equation $(A - 2I)\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ is when  $A - 2I = \mathbf{0_{(3,3)}}$ where $\mathbf{0_{(3,3)}}$ is the zero $3 \times 3$ matrix. Proving this is quite trivial. Given your matrix $A$, it is clear that $A - 2I \neq \mathbf{0_{(3,3)}}$, and as such we can conclude that $A$ has *at most* $2$ linearly independent eigenvectors, a fact which is given in the beginning of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the second statement, you know that the eigenspace is two dimensional, so any pair of linearly-independent eigenvectors form a basis for it. That’s really the content of the boxed text.

Expand the equation $\vec x_3=a\vec x_1+b\vec x_2$ in coordinates: $$au_1+bu_2 = u_3 \\ av_1+bv_2 = v_3.$$ Now solve for $a$ and $b$ using Cramer’s rule: $$a = {\begin{vmatrix}u_3&u_2\\v_3&v_2\end{vmatrix} \over \begin{vmatrix} u_1&u_2\\v_1&v_2 \end{vmatrix}} = {u_3v_2-u_2v_3\over u_1v_2-u_2v_1} \\
b = {\begin{vmatrix}u_1&u_3\\v_1&v_3\end{vmatrix} \over \begin{vmatrix} u_1&u_2\\v_1&v_2 \end{vmatrix}} = {u_1v_3-u_3v_1\over u_1v_2-u_2v_1}.$$ We know that the denominators are nonzero—the two equations are independent—because $\vec x_1$ and $\vec x_2$ are linearly independent.